# Creating matrix using map container

Tags: c++, matrix, dictionary, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading

```
   template < class A, class B, class C> class Matrix
  { 
    public:

   typedef map<B,C> M2; // for putting 1D info  
   typedef map<A,M2> M1;
   map<M1, M2 > data; 
   M1 m1;
   M2 m2;
   typedef  typename map<B,C>::iterator iterator2;
   iterator2 itr2; 
   typedef  typename map<A,M2>::iterator iterator1;
   iterator1 itr1;   
    Matrix()                             // default constructor
    { 
      m2.insert(pair<int,double> (1,10));
      m2.insert(pair<int,double> (2,20));
      m2.insert(pair<int,double> (3,30));
        m1.insert(pair <int, M2> (1,m2));
        m2.clear();

     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (1,40));
     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (2,50));
     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (3,60));
        m1.insert(pair <int, M2> (2,m2));
        m2.clear();

     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (1,70));
     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (2,80));
     m2.insert(pair<int,double> (3,90));
        m1.insert(pair <int, M2> (3,m2));
        m2.clear();                    }



    Matrix(const map<M1, M2>& ar)              //copy constructor 
    { m1 = ar.m1; }


    Matrix<A, B, C >& operator = (const Matrix<A, B, C >& ass)    //assignment
    { if (this==&ass) return *this;
      m1 = ass.m1; return *this; }


    const C& operator () ( int& index1,  int& index2 )  //for accessing/modifying data
     {    itr1 = m1.begin();
          advance(itr1,  index1 - 1);
          m2 = (*itr1).second;  
          itr2 = m2.begin();
          advance(itr2,  index2 - 1);             
          return (*itr2).second;      }
 };


int main()
{ 
  Matrix <int,int,double> mtr; 

   cout<< mtr(2,2);

    return 0;
  }
```

If I compile the above program I'm getting the following error "`cannot convert 'Matrix<int, int, double>' to 'double' in assignment.`"
I think there is a problem in *the way I have tried to overload the operators* but have been unable to solve it so far...

I know this isn't an efficient way of creating Matrices but since I'm a beginner ,it would help if you can help me understand the problem behind this code...

Problem Solved!
Thanks

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And is that the *only* error message? When posting questions about compiler errors, please include the complete and unedited error log.

Comment: should not be `m2.insert(pair<int,double> (1,10));` like `m2.insert(pair<B,C> (B(1),C(10)));` (also the `m1.insert(` (but thats not your problem. please add the line of the error)

Comment: another point: using maps to store a matrix would result in very bad performance in matrix computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one may not resolve all your problems but it's an outstanding issue:

```
Matrix <int,int,double> mtr();
```

This line of code doesn't do what you thought. It doesn't define object `mtr`, instead it declares function which returns `Matrix <int,int,double>` type.

To define object mtr

```
Matrix <int,int,double> mtr;
```

Also, map iterator is not random_access_iterator, you can't do

```
itr2 = m2.begin()+index2-1;
```

Try:

```
itr2 = std::advance(m2.begin(),  index2 - 1);
```