# C++ - Text file of 3 columns , find the value of 3rd column on the basis of 1st column. File is very large

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, tree

I have a text file with three columns and ":" as separator. I want to figure out the value of the third column after matching the user input data for column 1 and column 2. I have already implemented that using c++ structure with array. Any suggestion how to implement this using tree or maps for fast processing. All the three values are separate from each other. The file contains 200000 lines approx.  Combination of column 1 and column will always be unique.

```
1:1001:a
1:1002:a
1:1003:a
1:1005:b
1:1007:b
```

Comment: I am having problems to understand the exact behaviour you want? Could you please upload the array algorithm so that it is clearer?

Comment: You can find solution on this post [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449747/creating-matrix-using-map-container